# django-admin makemessages: how does it work with txt, xml and other files?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, internationalization, gettext

I am in the process of translating a Django app. I have translatable strings in files of a specific extensions (.vue files, but that's not very important for now).

I have to run the `makemessages` command to parse those strings and generate .po files.

The documentation says:

> **makemessages**: Runs over the entire source tree of the current directory and pulls
>   out all strings **marked for translation**.

Also, the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#makemessages) states that the default file extensions are: `html, txt, py` and gives an example with explicitly defined extentions:

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=de --extension=html,txt --extension xml
```

My question is: how is `makemessages` supposed to work with non-compiled files like `txt` and `xml`? How would I **mark string for translation** in files like that?

I know how to do this in a template or a .py file:

#### .html

```
{% trans "Text to be translated" %}
```

#### .py

```
gettext("Text to be translated")
# or
_("Text to be translated")
```

But what about other extensions? **.txt**, **.xml**? ... and eventually **.vue**?

Comment: `.vue` ask vue-taggeg question for Vue i18n (which is well described in official docs actually). `.txt, .xml` what about them? Can you use `gettext()` or `{% trans %}` inside those files?

Comment: `gettext()` is a python function (imported from `django.utils.translation`), `{% trans %}` is a tag made available in django templates, I tried using `gettext` in .xml files but it is ignored

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point of my question. The documentation mentions txt and xml files: `django-admin makemessages --locale=de --extension=html,txt --extension xml`

Comment: Ok, got it. Updated your question a little.

Comment: Thanks, that's more accurate indeed : )

Answer (score 8):

The `makemessages` command searches for files to translate and invokes the [`(x)gettext` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) to extract the strings marked for translation. It will behave differently depending on whether you tell it to use the `django` or `djangojs` `--domain`.

When using the `django` domain, it runs non-`.py` files through `django.utils.translation.templatize` to "Turn a Django template into something that is understood by `xgettext`"). It basically turns the whole file into `XXXXX` apart from the parts the lexer determines are relevant to `gettext`, which keeps the line numbers intact, etc.

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import templatize
>>> content = """This is a {% trans "test" %}!
... {# Translators: these comments remain intact for translators #}
... {% blocktrans %}Only applies to --domain=django and non-.py files {% endblocktrans %}
... 
... Everything else is {# ignored #}
... {% trans "EOM" %}
... :)"""
>>> print(templatize(content))
XXXX XX X  gettext(u'test') X
# Translators: these comments remain intact for translators
 gettext(u'Only applies to --domain=django and non-.py files ') SSSS SSSSSSS SS SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS SSS SSSSSSS SSSSS 

XXXXXXXXXX XXXX XX 
 gettext(u'EOM') 
XX
>>>
```

So for most non-Python, non-Django-template files, this will obliterate your translatable content.

When using the `djangojs` domain, Django won't perform any such preprocessing on the files. (For versions of `gettext` older than `0.18.3`, `makemessages` would call `django.utils.jslex.prepare_js_for_gettext`, which is somewhat less aggressive and just tweaks any escaping/regex syntax if necessary).

If you run `makemessages -a -d djangojs -e "js,vue"`, Django will tell `xgettext` to parse your `.js` and `.vue` files with [`--language=JavaScript`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#xgettext-Invocation) and a certain number of extra `--keyword` configurations to support `gettext_noop`, `gettext_lazy`, etc (`gettext` defaults to a `keywordspec` of `_, gettext, dgettext:2, dcgettext:2, ngettext:1,2, dngettext:2,3, pgettext:1c,2, dpgettext:2c,3` for `JavaScript`). `makemessages` will also pass `--from-code=UTF-8` and `--add-comments=Translators` arguments.

It's then over to `gettext` to do the parsing based on those specifications, and its own understanding of the files based on the `--language` specified.

Therefore your best bet for translating `.txt`, `.xml`, etc files with `makemessages` is to use the `djangojs` domain and see what `gettext` picks up based on `--language=JavaScript`, so you'd mark your strings as you would for JavaScript.

Or for Jinja2 templates, etc you could use an alternative solution such as [Babel's Message Extraction](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/messages.html#message-extraction)

Or you could even [customize `makemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#customizing-the-makemessages-command) to pass different parameters to `gettext` based on your requirements.

So for your Vue example...

If your `.vue` file contains calls to `gettext` in javascript code sections (default parsing doesn't seem to pick up on `gettext` calls within template attributes, etc) you should find that `makemessages` will extract these strings for translation (and `compilemessages` will generate the required binary files after the `.po` files are edited).

Then in order to see the translations when the code runs, you'll need to use the [Django JavaScript Catalog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n), so ensure you include something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>` in your code so that the `gettext` etc functions actually exist. (It sounds like you've already got this, but included for the sake of completeness.)

In your `.vue` files you could use something like:

```html
<script> // trick to ensure xgettext doesn't omit the code below: </closetag> 
    data(){
        const _ = gettext;
        // gettext default JavaScript keywordspec includes "_" shortcut
        // and should extract the strings below by default
        // -- or you could just use gettext('my string') directly
        return {                                                           
            heading: _('This is my translatable heading'),                                               
            button_text: _('Click here'),                                                                                      
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
    <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
    <button type="button">{{ button_text }}</button>
</template>
```

-- the strings should be translated based on the currently activated language courtesty of Django's translation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *any* of the content of those files to be dynamic, then you need to put them through some kind of parsing process.

There's absolutely no reason why you couldn't treat them as Django templates and render them through the normal Django template rending process; obviously without knowing what you are doing with those files it's impossible to give you specific advice, but you might want to use `render_to_string`. In itself, this doesn't have anything to do with translation or makemessages.

Comment: Let me explain: i'm planing to use the `gettext("Text to be translated")` javascript function. This function is defined in a file that already contains translated strings. So basically, I run the `makemessages` command, it generates a javascript file with a function and a large JSON object (containing the translated strings), then in any of my .js file (and hopefully .vue file), i'll be able to call `gettext("Text to be translated")`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext

Comment: OK. So what is your question?

Comment: Basically, calling the gettext function from a Vue.js component works (for existing translation strings only). My problem is that the when I want to add new strings to the translation catalog by running makemessages, the .vue files (or .xml, .txt) are ignored. They are processed (--verbosity 2 tells me so), but the translated strings don't get added to the .po file.